# How can I upload profile video via graph api?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video but found  nothing there.

So Can  I use graph api to upload video to be profile video(iOS App) ?

How's maximum size of video ?

How can I upload it ?

Any guide or tutorial will be please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upload a video to Facebook via Facebook graph API , check this:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

reference: [SCFacebook](https://github.com/lucascorrea/SCFacebook)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know what's maximum size and encode of profile video (mp4,wmv,m4v or else) ???

Comment: i used to upload .mp4