# How to share the video on Facebook Internally from Your App...?

Tags: ios, facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios/

I refer this link and others also.. but didnt gate the proper ans. so please help me!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078915/how-can-i-upload-profile-video-via-graph-api/40079136?noredirect=1#comment67431131_40079136